# SQL join key specified by a not-overlaping range

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I would like to join a table with a key defined by range. Classic approach like this is very slow:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.Index 
FROM table1 as A 
INNER JOIN  table2 as B
ON ID.Key BETWEEN B.IDfrom AND B.IDto
```

I have this set of tables:
[image: Key defined by ranges]

- ID and Index are both defined as primary keys clustered. I am not the
  owner of the db, so I have no rights to add or change the Primary of
  Foreign Keys.
- The ranges defined by `IDfrom` and `IDto` do not overlap. So
  theoretically just one column would be enough to determine if ID
  falls into a specified range.
- Of course, the tables 1 and 2 have other columns, not only those shown
  on a picture.

Since my tables are huge, the proposed classic solution is very slow, because SQL does not know that IDfrom is sorted ascending, and it has to check every row of Table2.

Query works pretty fast if I narrow ID range of Table1 to let's say 1000 rows. The only hopeless way I can see is to process everything in a loop determining ranges for ID from 1 to 1000 and then from 1001 to 2000 and so on. Is there no better solution for my problem?

Comment: Add index to IDFrom and IDTo

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I may not do that. As I stated I am not the owner of the db. I can only use it as it is.

Comment: Can we assume that IDFrom and IDTo do not overlap from row to row in Table2?  
Do your privileges allow you create an indexed view or temporary table?

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that

`The ranges defined by IDfrom and IDto do not overlap. So theoretically just one column would be enough to determine if ID falls into a specified range.`

You can try subquery but I don't know if it will be faster:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      IDFrom INT ,
      IDTo INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @Table1
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 ),
        ( 3 ),
        ( 4 ),
        ( 5 ),
        ( 6 ),
        ( 7 ),
        ( 8 ),
        ( 9 ),
        ( 10 ),
        ( 11 ),
        ( 12 )

INSERT  INTO @Table2
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 4, 4 ),
        ( 3, 5, 10 ),
        ( 4, 11, 12 )

SELECT  t1.ID AS ID1,
        ( SELECT    MIN(ID)
          FROM      @Table2 t2
          WHERE     t2.IDTo >= t1.ID
        ) AS ID2
FROM    @Table1 t1
```

Output:

```
ID1 ID2
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   3
10  3
11  4
12  4
```

Comment: Works crazy good! :-) It was like a draft slammed the door-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick.  Interleave the data and then use a cumulative maximum.

```
select id, table2index
from (select id, max(index) over (order by id) as table2index, index
      from (select id, NULL as index
            from table1
            union all
            select index, index as index
            from table2
           ) tt
      ) tt
where index is null;
```

Note:  this assumes that the index in `table2` is increasing.  Also, this requires SQL Server 2012+.  And, I've kept your column names, even though they will cause errors (`index` is a reserved word).